# Converter objeto jquery para html DOM

Tags: html, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
var valuePlan = variavel > 0 ? $('<a>').attr({
                                            target: '_blank',
                                            href: 'file.php'
                                           }).append( m.plan ) : ''
```

No código acima, eu verifico se a variável for maior que zero, então monte um link, senão fica vazia

Caso seja maior que zero gostaria de saber como mostrar no html como url

Tentei em fazer assim

```
  html( valuePlan  )
```

Mas dá o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: html
```

Gostaria que objeto acima se tornasse um link normal dentro de uma td que foi adicionada via javascript:

Exemplo:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Titulo</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tbody">
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  var variavel = 1
  var valuePlan = variavel > 0 ? $('<a>').attr({
                                                target: '_blank',
                                                href: 'file.php'
                                               }).append( m.plan ) : ''
  var cell = "<td>"+valuePlan+"</td>"
  $('.tbody).find('tr').remove()
  $('.tbody').append( cell )
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Então acho que o que você esta querendo é adicionar o elemento na pagina.

Para fazer isso você pode utilizar o [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) como você fez no seu elemento `<a>`, só que desta vez com um elemento que já esteja na pagina.

Exemplo: Digamos que você queira adicionar na propria `<body>` então você poderia utilizar algo como o codigo abaixo:

```
/// ; Como valuePlan pode ser uma string vazia vou fazer uma verificação antes
/// ;  para garantir que é um elemento jQuery
if( valuePlan instanceof jQuery )
    $("body").append( valuePlan )
```

---

Edição, exemplo usando como base seu código.

```js
var variavel = 1
var valuePlan = variavel > 0 ? $('<a>').attr({
       target: '_blank',
       href: 'file.php'
      }).append( "TESTE" ) : '';
      

var tbody = $('.tbody');

tbody.find("tr").remove();
    
   
var td = $("<td>")    /// cria TD
    .append( valuePlan ); /// adiciona A
    
var tr = $("<tr>") /// criar TR
      .append( td ); /// adiciona TD
      
tbody.append( tr ); /// adiciona TR ao tbody
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Titulo</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tbody">
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Um outro exemplo, usando uma classe unica na `td`

```js
var variavel = 1
var valuePlan = variavel > 0 ? $('<a>').attr({
       target: '_blank',
       href: 'file.php'
      }).append( "TESTE" ) : '';
      

var tbody = $('.tbody');


tbody.find("td.vai-receber-anchor") /// procura pela TD
   .html("") /// limpa a TD
   .append( valuePlan ); /// adiciona o valuePlan na TD
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Titulo</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tbody">
    <tr>
        <td class='vai-receber-anchor'></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Na verdade quero adicionar a uma célula de table via javascript. Ex "<TD>"+valueplan+"</TD>"

Comment: Então o metodo continua sendo o mesmo (`.append`), o que você tem que fazer é mudar o selector do jQuery, no exemplo eu coloquei o `"body"`, como você quer usar em uma `TD` você terar que fazer o selector de forma que chegue a essa `TD`, ou prepara-la para isso Ex. adicione a classe `"vai-receber-ahref"` na `TD` e no selector do jQuery ficaria assim:  `$("TD.vai-receber-ahre")` agora é so usar o `append` igual ao exemplo

Comment: Editei a pergunta, desculpa eu não ter sido claro

Comment: Então só é possível através de um elemento do dom, correto?

Comment: Não entendi essa ultima pergunta direito. -- Para adicionar na pagina você precisa adicionar a um elemento já esta na pagina. Agora criar você poderia criar ate como string Ex. `$("TD").append( "<a href='index.php'>Meu Link</a>" )`, Obs. nesse caso poderia usar ate o `.html( str )` ao invés de `.append( str )`